# How to trim UK postcodes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to only show the first letters of a UK postcode. For example if its `WV14 7AR` then i only want to show `WV`

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(30)
SET @v='WV14 7AR'
SELECT LEFT(@v,LEN(@v)-6)
```

This returns: `WV`

However if the postcode is: `WV4` then it will show: `W` and this is wrong.

Bare in mind you can get a UK postcode which could be 1 letter! 
A Birmingham postcode is: B1 2AR and therefore LEFT suggestion will fail.

Comment: If you want to display the first two letters, why don't you do a LEFT(,2) ?

Comment: `SELECT LEFT('WV14 7AR', 2)` or `SELECT SUBSTRING('WV14 7AR', 1, 2)`

Comment: because a postcode from Birmingham is: `B1 2AR` and therefore your LEFT suggestion will fail.

Comment: If it helps you search, that's called the postcode "Area". (e.g. there's an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81853fbc-5ecd-4b5d-a2d1-f188f3985fc6/how-to-extract-just-the-postcode-area-from-a-british-postcode?forum=sqlreportingservices).)

Comment: There are various things you might need to do but as usual, there are edge cases and therefore you need to describe whether you need to support 100% of cases or just the main ones. Most services that do something similar have to do a number of checks before they can provide what you want. There is no single answer that will work. Not all codes relate to area for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Special_cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show **just the first letters** of a UK postcode:

```
With Src (Postcode) As (
    Select 'B1 1AB' Union All
    Select 'W1A 1AB' Union All
    Select 'WV14 1AB' Union All
    Select 'GIR 1AB'
)
Select
    Postcode,
    RTRIM(LEFT(Postcode, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Postcode) - 1)) As FirstLetters
From Src
```

---

```
Postcode    FirstLetters
--------    ------------
B1 1AB      B
W1A 1AB     W
WV14 1AB    WV
GIR 1AB     GIR
```

---

**Upd**: non-UK Postcodes such as all-letter can be either filtered out with

```
Where Postcode Like '%[0-9]%'
```

or even stricter

```
Where Postcode Like '[a-z]%[0-9]%[a-z]'
```

or handled with

```
CASE WHEN Postcode Like '%[0-9]%'
    THEN RTRIM(LEFT(Postcode, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Postcode) - 1))
    ELSE Postcode
END As FirstLetters
```

Comment: If i run, "SELECT DISTINCT POSTCODE FROM CONTACT" i get Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 0):

Assumtion : Extract part before the first integer

```
  DECLARE @v VARCHAR(30)
    SET @v='WV14 7AR'
    SELECT case when (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @v)) >2 then left(@v,2) else left(@v,1) end
```

Comment: There is GIR Postcode Area: [List of postcode districts in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom)