# Trim UK Postcodes in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring, trim

I know a similar question [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150707/how-to-trim-uk-postcodes) but that solution doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

What i'm trying to do; create new columns with copy of the full postcode and then trim this down first to sector, then trim that to district, and finally to area. ie. Copy postcode to postcode_sector trim postcode_sector.

`TA15 1PL` becomes:

- `TA15 1` for sector
- `TA15` for district
- `TA` for area.

What I've tried:

Create new columns in table for each, then;

```
SELECT postcode_sector FROM postcodes
RTRIM (Left([postcode_sector],(Len([postcode_sector])-2)) + " " + 
Right([postcode_sector],3));
```

Throws syntax error;

```
Select
Postcode,
RTRIM(LEFT(Postcode, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Postcode) - 1)) As AreaTest
From postcodes
```

Doesn't work as no PATINDEX function in PostgresSQL. From here I have looked at an alternate approach using `SUBSTRING` function elped by the excellent tutorial [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/) . Using;

```
SELECT 
substring (postcode FROM 1 FOR 6) AS postcode_sector
FROM postcodes;
```

Gets me part way I now have a column with TA15 1 but due to the way the system works i also have T15 1A. Is there a way in PostgresSQL to count the number of characters in a cell and delete one? Out of wider interest is it faster to use `TRIM` than `SUBSTRING` I'm executing across the full postcode file which is ~27million rows

Comment: Of course the first query throws a syntax error. Strings are concatenated with `||` in SQL. And square brackets are illegal in an SQL identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with UK post codes, but according to [Wikipedia's format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom), this should handle all cases:

```
select postcode,
       m[1] || m[2] || ' ' || m[3] sector,
       m[1] || m[2] district,
       m[1] area
from   src,
       regexp_matches(postcode, '^([A-Z]{1,2})([0-9A-Z]{1,2}) ([0-9])([A-Z]{2})') m
```

http://rextester.com/KREPX19406

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that gets everything in the England and Wales postcode set without returning NULLS

Comment: As someone new to SQL is there away to run this and add to the original table rather than run export result and join back in?

Comment: You could create a simple view around this query, there is no need to duplicate data. -- Because the `UPDATE` syntax is troublesome, i can't think of any easy way which doesn't require a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
with postcodes (postcode) as (
  values ('TA15 1PL')
)
select substring(postcode from '[^0-9]{2}[0-9]+ [0-9]') as sector, 
       substring(postcode from '[^0-9]{2}[0-9]+') as district,
       substring(postcode from '([^0-9]+)') as area
from postcodes;
```

returns

```
sector | district | area
-------+----------+-----
TA15 1 | TA15     | TA
```

Comment: Thank you that works for those, needs some modification to work for all postcodes due to their formatting. It's struggling with  WC1E 7JT returning NULL for sector but WC1 for district and WC for area